PDF-TeX sync to Skim with Emacs 29.4 doesn't work
I have the code from the Skim documentation relating to PDF-TeX synchronization (https://sourceforge.net/p/skim-app/wiki/TeX_and_PDF_Synchronization/#setting-up-emacs) in my init.el file. This used to work. At some point it stopped working, and when I try to load a tex file in emacs I get the message Font-lock trying to use keywords before setting them up. If I comment out the lines, the message goes away, but sync doesn't work.
Has something changed in either emacs or skim (or Auctex)? Where should I be looking to figure out what's broken?
For reference, here is the section dealing with LaTeX in my init.el file:
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)
;; Tell Emacs to stop using tabs
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)

;; Don't ask for section labels
(setq LaTeX-section-label nil)

;; Use PDF mode by default
(setq-default TeX-PDF-mode t)
;; Make emacs aware of multi-file projects
(setq-default TeX-master nil)
;; Allow Skim to be able to jump to the relevant page in the PDF document
;; The following only works with AUCTeX loaded
(require 'tex-site)
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook
     (lambda ()
         (add-to-list 'TeX-output-view-style
             '("^pdf$" "."
               "/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline %n %o %b")))
)

UPDATE: my new init file (at least the portion dealing with latex):
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)

;; Make emacs aware of multi-file projects
(setq-default TeX-master nil)

;; Tell Emacs to stop using tabs
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)

;; Don't ask for section labels
(setq LaTeX-section-label nil)

;; Allow Skim to be able to jump to the relevant page in the PDF document
;; The following only works with AUCTeX loaded
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "displayline")))

(setq TeX-view-program-list
      '(("displayline"
         "/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline %n %o %b"
         "displayline")))


Which version of AUCTeX are using?  And how did you install it?

When you install AUCTeX from ELPA (which is nowadays the only way to install AUCTeX), you really don't need
(require 'tex-site)

in your init file, so better you remove that.  Further, the variable TeX-output-view-style is removed from AUCTeX.  Selecting viewers is done via TeX-view-program-selection and TeX-view-program-list.  On macOS, you need this in your init file in order to use Skim:
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "displayline")))

(setq TeX-view-program-list
      '(("displayline"
         "/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline %n %o %b"
         "displayline")))

The entry from Skim wiki is obsolete.

For me, forward and backward search both work in a setup like this: The general directory layout of the files looks like this:
.
├── Temp
│   └── sub-file.tex
└── mwe.ltx

Where the mwe.ltx contains:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

This is some text.
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:1}
  a + b = c
\end{equation}

\include{Temp/sub-file.tex}

\begin{verbatim}
Some verbatim text
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: LaTeX
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% TeX-source-correlate-mode: t
%%% End:

and Temp/sub-file.tex contains:
This is some text in a sub-file.

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: LaTeX
%%% TeX-master: "../mwe.ltx"
%%% End:


I saw you posted to the Skim list. I'll try those changes and see what happens. Thanks.

I've made the changes you suggest; now, when I ask to display the PDF (from a subsidiary tex file, if that matters), I get the message "Cannot find displayline viewer. Select another one in 'TeX-view-program-selection'." I've annotated my original post above with a paste of my current latex stuff in my emacs startup. I've verified that the path given for Skim displayline actually works. Can you help? (Sorry for the newbie questions, but I'm pretty lost here.)

Further, if I replace the third element of the program-list item with "Skim", I no longer get an error, but Skim is not synchronized with the Emacs buffer.

@rogerl - Before we proceed: Which version of AUCTeX are using? And how did you install it?

Using 14.0.6, installed thru the package manager from ELPA. Also emacs 29.4 on MacOS 14.5.

@rogerl - See the updated answer.  Maybe you can come up with a short example exhibiting the issue.

Hmm. I set up exactly that example, and when I click in "some text in a sub-file" and then click the button in the emacs toolbar that should navigate to that text in the PDF, the PDF is displayed at the start of the file.

In a larger PDF, Skim gets focus at the point in the file that was in view before editing the PDF and reprocessing.

@rogerl - Do you activate the TeX-source-correlate-mode minor-mode?  I missed to mention it explicitly since I presumed you turned it on.  Can you try the adjusted files in my answer?

@rogerl - And also, open mwe.ltx, hit C-c C-c LaTeX RET, once finished, do C-c C-c View RET and you see the command which Emacs will use to start the viewer, hit RET again to confirm.

The command was open -a Skim.app mwe.pdf.
I did not include TeX-source-correlate-mode. Putting it into the suffix of mwe.ltx seemed to have no effect.

@rogerl - There is the problem, you should see something like this: /Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline 15 mwe.pdf mwe.ltx.

@rogerl - You can try starting Emacs with emacs -Q, then eval'ing this (progn (package-initialize t) (package-activate 'auctex) (setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "displayline"))) (setq TeX-view-program-list '(("displayline" "/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline %n %o %b" "displayline")))) in the scratch buffer (i.e., put the cursor after the last ) and hit C-x C-e), and then open mwe.ltx as above and compile and view the file.  Please tell if this recipe works.

That results in 1. Command (default View): , I said RET; then 2. Start Emacs server for inverse search in viewer? (y or n): y, then 3. Cannot find "displayline" viewer. Select another one in 'TeX-view-program-selection'.

@rogerl - TBH, I'm running out of ideas since I can use the above without any problems.  I've installed Skim via Homebrew, but that should be a footnote.  And I start Emacs from the CLI and not as an App, but that shouldn't make a difference either.

@rogerl - And maybe this bit is relevant, but again, I can't tell since I'm not using Emacs as an macOS-App.

I also start emacs from the CLI, using a script that also starts an emacs server if one doesn't exist and otherwise opens a window in the existing server. I installed emacs using Homebrew. No idea how I installed Skim. (The fact that emacs manages to open Skim at all seems to me to imply that it's not a permissions problem, but who knows.)

May I send you my emacs zsh function that invokes emacs and starts a server if necessary together with my emacs startup files, just as a last try?

@rogerl - Yes, please send the function.  You can also drop a line to auctex@gnu.org and ask there, maybe someone else can reproduce the issue.

I can post them here, but is there a way to send you a DM in stack exchange? If not, is your email your name (with a dot perhaps between first and last) @gnu.org? Thanks.

@rogerl - I don't think SX has a DM functionality.  Again, I suggest you send a mail to auctex@gnu.org and ask there for help, maybe referencing this thread.  Long comments here are not ideal for this kind of problem solving.
